# Already registered a copy: org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.select.SqmSubQuery. Getting this error for below code, how to fix it

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, criteria, hibernate-6.x

```
    public static<T> Long getRows(final EntityManager em, final CriteriaQuery<T> criteria) {
        final CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
        final CriteriaQuery<Long> countCriteria = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
        final Root<T> root = countCriteria.from(cb.getResultType());
        countCriteria.select(cb.count(root));

        for(final Root<?> rootObj: criteria.getRoots()){
            countCriteria.getRoots().add(rootObj);
        }
        
        final Predicate whereRes = criteria.getRestriction();
        if(whereRes != null){
            countCriteria.where(whereRes);
        }

        final Predicate groupRes = criteria.getGroupRestriction();
        if(groupRes != null){
            countCriteria.having(groupRes);
        }
        
        countCriteria.groupBy(criteria.getGroupList());
        countCriteria.distinct(criteria.isDistinct());
        
        return em.createQuery(countCriteria).getSingleResult();

}
}
```

**I am facing this issue in code after upgrading to spring boot 3, hibernate 6 on last line of the function above. Please suggest.TIA**

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by this way.

```html
ublic Long count() {
        var countBuilder = (HibernateCriteriaBuilder) builder; //CriteriaBuilder from class level
        var countQuery = countBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        var subQuery = countQuery.subquery(Tuple.class);

        var sqmSubQuery = (SqmSubQuery<Tuple>) subQuery;
        var sqmOriginalQuery = (SqmSelectStatement) query; // CriteriaQuery from class level
        var sqmOriginalQuerySpec = sqmOriginalQuery.getQuerySpec();
        var sqmSubQuerySpec = sqmOriginalQuerySpec.copy(SqmCopyContext.simpleContext());

        sqmSubQuery.setQueryPart(sqmSubQuerySpec);
        Root<?> subQuerySelectRoot = subQuery.getRoots().iterator().next();
        sqmSubQuery.multiselect(subQuerySelectRoot.get("id").alias("id"));

        countQuery.multiselect(countBuilder.count(countBuilder.literal(1)));
        countQuery.from(sqmSubQuery.distinct(true).orderBy(builder.asc(subQuerySelectRoot.get("id"))));

        return entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
    }
```

OR
research
this post https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-17410

UPD I have strange problems with previous version (sometimes it tried to request object from another request table), so now it looks like:

```html
public Long count(CriteriaBuilder builder, CriteriaQuery query) {
        var countBuilder = (HibernateCriteriaBuilder) builder;
        var countQuery = countBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
        var subQuery = countQuery.subquery(Tuple.class);

        var sqmSubQuery = (SqmSubQuery<Tuple>) subQuery;
        var sqmOriginalQuery = (SqmSelectStatement) query;
        var sqmOriginalQuerySpec = sqmOriginalQuery.getQuerySpec();
        var sqmSubQuerySpec = sqmOriginalQuerySpec.copy(SqmCopyContext.simpleContext());
        sqmSubQuery.setQueryPart(sqmSubQuerySpec);
        Root<?> subQuerySelectRoot = subQuery.getRoots().iterator().next();

        sqmSubQuery.multiselect(subQuerySelectRoot.get("id").alias("id"));

        countQuery.multiselect(countBuilder.count(countBuilder.literal(1)));
        countQuery.from(sqmSubQuery.distinct(true).orderBy(builder.asc(subQuerySelectRoot.get("id"))));
        return entityManager.createQuery(countQuery).getSingleResult();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**